# Filtering VBA in Access Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form called Review List that shows all requests, but I only want to show certain records that need to be reviewed.  I would like that when the form loads, only those records with a [RequestStatus] of "Submitted" or "Re-Submitted" to show in the list.  I can get the VBA code to filter based on one of the values, but I can't figure out how to get it to filter both values.

I know this is probably easy, but I can't find an answer to this and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure VBA code is needed.  You could use a query as the form's Record Source and include a `WHERE` clause to restrict the rows displayed, per your condition:

```sql
WHERE [RequestStatus] IN ('Submitted', 'Re-Submitted')
```

But if you want to use VBA to apply a filter instead ...

```vb
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = "[RequestStatus] IN ('Submitted', 'Re-Submitted')"
Debug.Print strFilter '<- examine this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way (perhaps simpler). You don't need any vba or even modify your recordsource. Just ensure that in the Form's Recordsource the [RequestStatus] field is included and then, in the Form Filter, add the following

Status= 'Submitted' Or Status ='Re-Submitted'

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7LYT.png)